# Grid View Row Data Bound event

Tags: asp.net

I can't run on IIS Server. I write with dynamically create link button in gridvew row data bound and Link button can't redirect access to file server. I only can on visual studio. Please let me know, how to solve it.

```
protected void GVSample_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.`enter code here`RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string variable = e.Row.Cells[8].Text.ToString();
                string[] stringSeparators = { ";" };
                string[] result;
                result = variable.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

                foreach (string s in result)
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                        lb.Text = s.ToString() + "<br />";
                        lb.CommandName = "ApproveVacation";
                        lb.Command += LinkButton_Command;
                        e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(lb);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

protected void LinkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string val = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
            int row = -1;
            int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out row);
            if (row == -1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "alert('Fail to Open File');", true);
                return;
            }
            GridViewRow gdrow = GridView1.Rows[row];
            DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.GridView1.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];
            if (e.CommandName == "ApproveVacation")
            {
                try
                {
                    string username = "Bla";
                    string password = "bla";
                    System.Net.NetworkCredential readCredentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

                    string filepath = @"\\192.168.1.100\SAPAttachments\abc";
                    using (new NetworkConnection(filepath, readCredentials))
                    {
                        WebClient User = new WebClient();
                        string file = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
                        string a = @"<br />";
                        file = file.Replace(a, "");
                        foreach (var item in file)
                        {
                            Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(file);
                            string stringCutted = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                            if (stringCutted == "docx" || stringCutted == "DOCX")
                            {
                                if (FileBuffer != null)
                                {
                                    Context.Response.Clear();
                                    FileInfo Sourcefile = new FileInfo(file);
                                    Context.Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
                                    Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Sourcefile.Name);
                                    Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", Sourcefile.Length.ToString());
                                    Context.Response.WriteFile(Sourcefile.FullName);
                                    Context.Response.End();
                                }
                            }

                            if (stringCutted == "pdf" || stringCutted == "PDF")
                            {
                                if (FileBuffer != null)
                                {
                                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                                    Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
                                    Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
                                    Response.End();
                                }
                            }


                            if (stringCutted == "jpg" || stringCutted == "JPG" || stringCutted == "jpeg" || stringCutted == "JPEG")
                            {
                                if (FileBuffer != null)
                                {
                                    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                                    Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
                                    Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
                                    Response.End();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "alert('Success');", true);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "alert('Fail to Open File');", true);
                }
            }
        }
```